# Any ReactJs component framework that can replace ionic?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ratchet-2

Currently, my weekend project is using ionic framework.

I think angularjs is fine but ReactJs is much more flexible and fast.

Any ReactJs component framework (mainly css + some common thing like ftScroller will be totally enough) that can replace ionic?

I tried http://goratchet.com/ and plus all my hacks. But many small effects will be missed. Ex: click effect or text selection.

That is weekend projects, it will be too hard to maintain all the small things.
(My weekend project - App to send full size photo to any phone number: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eddyy.app)

I am looking for a Cordova/Phonegap solution that can build similar projects above. Please help!

Comment: Check out http://reapp.io/ and http://touchstonejs.io/

Comment: It should not be too hard to use ionic CSS together with React. Of course the behaviour, e.g. of `<slide-box>` is lost and has to be implemented with React. But you have well-styled components.

Comment: Try Ionic for React: https://pors.github.io/reactionic